# How can I resize and center a selection in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a number of forms in Tiff format that arrive with all sorts of different scan qualities.  Most troubling to our OCR system is the magnification, so I'm trying to standardize the magnification using Photoshop.

Here's what I've tried-
Option 1:

Select using the color selection tool(picking black).
Transform to new size.
Copy and paste to a new layer.

-Problem:  Quality is lost in the transformation process.

Option 2:

Select using the color selection tool(picking black).
Copy and paste to a new layer.
Convert to smart layer.
Scale to size.

-Problem:  Image is no longer centered on the page.

This will eventually be automated using scripting so it's important that I can do this in the UI without mouse input (dragging, resizing etc.)
[image: Forms look similar to this (8.5x11 page)]

Comment: This might be  better asked at Photography StackExchange, https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you looked into using image size for this?

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing you can do to "increase" the scan quality. If it comes in at a lower quality, that's that.**

However, you can standardise the size at which the scan appears in whatever intended use case you have. However you save the file, when you drop it into something else, you can resize it using a number of methods. You're best doing it this way around (rather than resizing first and saving, as then you're only increasing the file size without really adding any information).

I would use a process as:

- Use Magic Wand with high tolerance (e.g. 50) and with Contiguous disabled
- Click the white area to select the "page"
- Invert Selection to select all the black
- Crop: you now have an image that is tightly cropped to the actual content, so you're not wasting bytes on white space and your image sizing is standardised to the actual width of the content

Then the question is **where do you want the scan to appear** at a standard size? The general answer here is that, whenever you place the image into some other context, you need to use whatever resizing tools exist *at that point* to set the standard size.